# A contexually significant, but syntactically small, edit was rejected - adding spaces to indicate 'code'

Tags: bug

I was doing some review of edits on Stack Overflow and was asked to look at an edit to the following answer:

*[Why is GetIsNetworkAvailable() always returning true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457407/why-is-getisnetworkavailable-always-returning-true/13457591#13457591)*

The edit added a missing brace character, but it also *removed* the indentation on the code sample, so it would show up as poorly-formatted text instead of nicely-formatted code. I clicked the "improve edit" button and added the indentation back in, but the system would not allow me to save my changes because they were not significant enough.

While my change was only adding space characters, because of [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) formatting it substantially changed the look of the answer. It would be great if the significance-detector could be smarter about this scenario. (Sorry, I don't have a suggestion for actually implementing this additional smartness.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the suggested edit now, I don't see any missing spaces. Since editors can go back and update their edits (which doesn't leave any record of the original, as far as I know), I assume that's what happened here.

I'm guessing that they originally made the edit without the spaces. Then you were shown that version of the suggested edit. While you were reviewing it, they updated the suggestion, making the exact same change that you wanted to. Then, when you tried to submit, your "improvement" was identical to the new suggestion, so it was blocked.

With more than 2K, your edits shouldn't ever be prevented for being too minor, so I think this is the only scenario which would cause that to happen.

Comment: That makes sense - thanks for explaining it.

Comment: On the other hand - I went to the answer, and it looks like the original edit (which adds a missing brace after the 'try' keyword, in addition to the formatting change) hasn't been applied yet - the brace is still missing. I suppose the first editor may have made the change you suggested, but it still hasn't been accepted by the system.

Comment: @Bruce True, but I think that since you were trying to update it, it doesn't matter. It's still going to look for a change between your edit and the pending one.